# Chat communication

Tags: php, pdo

I've an question about my chat application. If you communicate as user with an admin, you can see the communication from both sides, how can i call that from the DB.

DB,

```
record 1: user_from, user_to, message
record 2: user_to, user_from, message
```

sql:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_from = 1 AND user_to = 2
```

But with this query i can get only one way. I can see now only the records where `user_from` 1 and `user_to` 2 is, but i also want to see where `user_from` 2 and `user_to` 1 is.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OR` and add your second condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
WHERE (user_from = 1 AND user_to = 2) 
   OR (user_from = 2 AND user_to = 1)
```